# Old static IP address returns after reboot (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: networking, dhcp, ip

I have Ubuntu server 20.04 running on my home network as a media server and for storage. I changed ISP's recently (I live in the country and am limited on my ISP choices) and they don't allow me to change the IP addressing for DHCP or for me to turn it off. I changed the IP on the server but every time I reboot, the old static IP address returns as a second IP for the adapter. Also, for some reason, an IPv6 address is assigned even though netplan has dhcp6 disabled.

I can delete the addresses until I reboot. I had created a script to clear the stale IPs, but I would like to know why it seems to want to hold onto the old stuff. I've verified that all DHCP services are off, nothing running in the background. Here are my netplan settings.

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      addresses: [192.168.12.20/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.12.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.12.1,8.8.8.8]
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      addresses: [192.168.12.21/24]
  version: 2
```

Here's the output from `ip -br a`

```
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8 ::1/128 
enp2s0           UP             192.168.12.20/24 192.168.1.20/24 XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX/128 XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX/64 XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX/64 
enp3s0           UP             192.168.12.21/24 192.168.1.21/24 XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX/128 XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX/64 XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX/64
```

Deleting the IP is only a temporary fix. Once I reboot, the IP shows back up. Also, I've noticed that if I re-apply the netplan, the IPv6 address will get reapplied but the IPv4 address won't. Here's the script I'm running to remove the addresses.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo ip a d 192.168.1.20 dev enp2s0
sudo ip a d 192.168.1.21 dev enp3s0
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
```

Does anyone have any clue that can direct me to solving this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple .yaml files in the netplan directory, netplan will use all of them when you generate and apply the config.

Ran into this issue myself. Changing the extension of my old yaml version file resolved the issue and I only get the ip-addresses from the desired yaml config